# Replacing and counting values in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of items which are ids

```
 var names = ['1','2', '1', '3'];
```

Then with this id i make an ajax request expecting to receive the name for each id and replace it with it;

```
 var names = ['ham','cheese', 'ham', 'onion'];
```

And finally show a list like this:

```
 ham x2, cheese, onion
```

The problem is i get this instead:

```
 ham x2, cheese, ham, onion
```

How can i do that?

here is my code

```
var list = [];

function _checkIngredients(pizza, ingredient) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list[pizza].ingredients.length; ++i) {
        if (list[pizza].ingredients[i] == ingredient) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

pizzas.get().then(function (response) {
    list = response.data;
    angular.forEach(list, function (v, k) {
        //Find ingredients names per pizza
        angular.forEach(v.ingredients, function (i, ik) {
            ingPerPizza.get(i).then(function (response) {
                var name = response.data.name;
                if ( _checkIngredients(k, name) ) {
                    list[k].ingredients[ik] = '2x' + name;
                } else {
                    list[k].ingredients[ik] = name;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show what the raw data looks like that you get back for each request: `pizzas.get()` and `ingPerPizza.get({id})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an external library like lodash or underscore, in this case the countBy function works nicely:

```
var list = ['ham','cheese', 'ham', 'onion'];
$scope.result = _.countBy( list );
```

Result would be:

```
{
  "ham": 2,
  "cheese": 1,
  "onion": 1
}
```

Then print it out:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in result">{{key}} x{{data}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store all ingredients in an array and then group them by name with `underscore's` (http://underscorejs.org/#) `_.groupBy` function.

```
pizzas.get().then(function (response) {
    list = response.data;
    angular.forEach(list, function (v, k) {
        //Find ingredients names per pizza

        var ingredients = [];
        angular.forEach(v.ingredients, function (i, ik) {
            ingPerPizza.get(i).then(function (response) {
                ingredients.push({name: response});
            }
        }
        ingredients = _.groupBy(ingredients,'name');
        //do something what you want with this object and attach to pizza       
    });
});
```

Now in ingredients you will get something like:

```
{
  "ham": [
    {
      "name": "ham"
    },
    {
      "name": "ham"
    }
  ],
  "cheese": [
    {
      "name": "cheese"
    }
  ],
  "onion": [
    {
      "name": "onion"
    }
  ]
```

So you can easily check quantity of each ingriendt by using `ingredients['cheese'].length`.

You can also display them with something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in ingredients">{{key}} x {{data.length}}</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/7gfs27zz/

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Array and Object natives to provide this functionality. This will return: ["ham: 2", "cheese: 1", "onion: 1"].

```
     var names = ['ham','cheese', 'ham', 'onion'];

     Array.prototype.compileObj = function() {

        var instances = {};

        this.forEach( function( element, index ) { 

            if ( instances[element]) {
                instances[element]+= 1
            }

            else { 
                instances[element] = 1;
            }


        });

        return instances
    }

    Object.prototype.toArr = function() {

        var returnArr = [],
            obj = this;

        Object.keys( obj ).forEach( function( element, index) {

            returnArr.push( element + ': ' + obj[element] );

        });

        return returnArr;
    }

    console.log( names.compileObj().toArr() )
```